# PhoneGap native app error. "Illegal access"

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app, phonegap-cli

I am new to PhoneGap app development framework. I created a simple app which picks up user location and plots it on Google map. I am using PhoneGap desktop app, and I am able to run my app on IE and Firefox by pinging the IP. But it throws an error "Error(1): Only secure origins are allowed." when I am running in Chrome browser.

I used PhoneGap cloud build platform and created packages for Android native app. After installation, while running the app I am getting the error: "Error(1): Illegal access."

Can anyone please tell me the way to fix these issues?

Thank you.

Comment: @ If you are testing it in Android Marshmallow, it could be a possible permission issue.

Comment: No. It is Jelly Bean.

Comment: Could you post your code snippet? Are you using any plugins for this?

Comment: [Phonegap Desktop App – What it is and is not](https://unbot.wordpress.com/?p=457&shareadraft=5716d98464be5) -- Read this FAQ for a better understanding  [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: I fixed the problem. The issue was the way I used to create the build. I had not included config.xml file. 
But the chrome issue I could not fix. I followed the following url for creating the app.  [Link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/implement-google-maps-api-on-phonegap-using-the-device-api.html)